# Unsupported Get Request when using fbrads package in R

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I keep trying to use the fbrads package but cannot seem to get past the initial fbad_int command here is the code:

> fbad_init(accountid = acc_id, token=fb_tkn, version = '2.11')

Here is the error:

> ERROR [2017-12-06 16:14:20] Header: {"Strict-Transport-Security":["max-age=15552000; preload"],"x-fb-trace-id":["BBXrayTueRW"],"x-fb-rev":["3505327"],"Content-Type":["application/json; charset=UTF-8"],"facebook-api-version":["v2.11"],"Cache-Control":["no-store"],"Pragma":["no-cache"],"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":["*"],"Expires":["Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"],"WWW-Authenticate":["OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"Unsupported get request.\""],"X-FB-Debug":["Qbz9OGraEi8CWYhMxbOod9Ek+1SxslzvCqx8p8gzaO39gUQkEJs7EU1zYIhqGqUNosA1FJcDWNANUF+olFIV0A=="],"Date":["Wed, 06 Dec 2017 21:14:21 GMT"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Content-Length":["116"],"status":["400"],"statusMessage":["Bad Request"]}
>   ERROR [2017-12-06 16:14:20] Body: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"BBXrayTueRW"}}
>   Error in fbad_request(path = paste0("act_", accountid, "/"), method = "GET",  : 
>     Unsupported get request.

Here is my session info:

> R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Packages:

> fbRads_2.10.0    Rfacebook_0.6.15 httpuv_1.3.5     rjson_0.2.15     httr_1.3.1

Everything has been updated to the latest version through devtools, I have checked the tokens and they are all valid, I have disabled the sandbox environment in the facebook api, and have followed instructions listed on the GITHUB of the fbRADS package but still receiving the same error.

Comment: _“I have checked the tokens and they are all valid”_ - so what, that doesn’t necessarily mean that you actually _have access_ to whatever object you want to read here ... What are you trying to read here, user profile data? What kind of access token are you using, where/how did you create it, and what permissions does it include?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I have created the app in an effort to read campaign data and potentially create custom audiences for targeting. I have ad ids, and I'm trying to initially just read the live campaigns under that specific ad id. Subsequently i'll create custom audiences for targeting. Based on the package creator's video the base/default app setup on facebook should be sufficient